# AWS EFS CloudWatch metrics TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes max stat showing a cap of 1.05M

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-efs

I'm collecting throughput metrics of my application that uses AWS EFS (Amazon Elastic File System). My question is: why my CloudWatch metrics shows that the max stat of TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes of my EFS system caps at ~1.05M?

**Sample graph of the Max stat of TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes**
[image: Sample graph of the Max stat of TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes]

While the sum of these stats shows much higher (GBs):

**Sample graph of the Sum stat of TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes**
[image: Sample graph of the Sum stat of TotalIOBytes/DataReadIOBytes]

It's not clear where does this 1.05M come from and what exactly is my application's file system throughput per second.

I have read through EFS official docs including [performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html), [tips](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance-tips.html), [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#soft-limits) and [metrics explanation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-metrics.html) but none of them seems to provide an answer. The performance link does mention that there is a 1M threshold (but also worth noting that it is lower-bound) for EFS system that has very little storage usage but my application uses more than 200GB.

I also tried configuring [provisioned throughput](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-throughput-for-amazon-elastic-file-system-efs/) but it didn't seem to make a difference.

There is a seemingly very similar question asked in [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUzQ9y6AtYSASYhQSRwwR8Fw/efs-throughput-not-exceeding-1-mb).

Answer (score 0):

> While the sum of these stats shows much higher (GBs)

this metric is not reporting throughput (Bytes per seconds), it's reporting Bytes.
from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-metrics.html) linked in the question

> The Sum statistic is the total number of bytes associated with all file system operations.

Using the Sum statistic, each point on the graph is showing the amount of bytes for a certain period of time (defined in your chart, but not visible in the screenshots). While the Maximum statistic is the size of the largest operation during such period.

Example situation:

- 1 MBps throughput limit
- the period in the dashboard set to 1 hour
- the application almost hitting the limit for 1 hour consecutively

In this case, we may see

- the Maximum stat plotting a 1MB: biggest operation in the period cannot exceed the throughput limit
- the Sum stat plotting a number less than 3600 MBps (3600 seconds in 1 hour period)